# How to calculate events per second in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, read-write

I have a single node elastic search cluster. It throws errors that read and write events per second is more than 10,000. I want to know that how we can find out number of read/write operations in elastic search. Once I know the number of read/writes per second, I would be able to scale the cluster.

Comment: I am currently working on it. Will surly respond back and upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable [stack monitoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-monitoring.html) for your cluster and get all the required details related to cluster [performance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/elasticsearch-metrics.html).

You can follow [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/configuring-monitoring.html) documentation for enable cluster monitoring from Kibana.

Comment: Is there a way to get the information via curl commands?

Comment: Yes you can do that because data will be store in Elasticsearch index and same is shown in Kibana dashboard. so you can access data using underlying index. You can also check [Cluster State API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-stats.html)

Comment: Although I am not able to calculate events per second but I successfully found how to get the number of events.  @Sagar